# How to reset a variable

Tags: android, null, int, increment

I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious or whether this is actually something I don't know how to do, but I'd like to be able to reset some variables (`integers`). I have a method that increments them, and they're saved in `SharedPreferences`. I'd like to be able to reset these to 0 on a button click.

I can clear `SharedPreferences` using the clear(); command, but the ints stay the same so as soon as they are called again they are back to what they were before the reset. I've also tried setting them equal to 0, but then I can't increment them any more. Is there a way to just reset or delete variables?

Or, if that's not possible/too difficult, is there another way I can completely reset these ints?

Thanks

This is part of the incrementing code. This works. I can also clear `SharedPreferences`; that part is fine too. *The only part that doesn't work is resetting the int to 0, but keeping it incrementable*.

```
Button PlusOneButton = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.plusonebutton));
        PlusOneButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                intName++;
}});
```

EDIT: the final code that works

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class ThirdScreenActivity extends Activity {

    public int myIntPlusOne;

    public static final String PREFS = "MyPrefsFile";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen2);

        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
        myIntPlusOne = sharedPrefs.getInt("myIntPlusOneSaved", 0);


    if ("ListView Item 1".equals(position)) {

        myIntPlusOne = sharedPrefs.getInt("myIntPlusOneSaved", 0);

        TextView PlusOne = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.plusonetextview));
        PlusOne.setText(String.valueOf(myIntPlusOne));

        Button PlusOneButton = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.plusonebutton));
        PlusOneButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                myIntPlusOne++;
              TextView PlusOne = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.plusonetextview));
              PlusOne.setText((myIntPlusOne)+"");

              SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
              Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
              editor.putInt("myIntPlusOneSaved", myIntPlusOne);
              editor.commit();
            }
        });
    }

    else if... 
    }

      Button btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearbtn);
      btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
              myIntPlusOne=0;
              TextView PlusOne = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.plusonetextview));
              PlusOne.setText("0");
       }
      });

    }

        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();

            SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
            Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
            editor.putInt("myIntPlusOneSaved", myIntPlusOne);
            editor.commit();
         }
}
```

Comment: If you can write to `SharedPreferences`, you should also be able to set the int to `0`. Can you post some code to clarify your problem?

Comment: Are you sure you have called editor.commit();

Comment: By 'incrementing' , do you mean multiplying with 2? Then it will not increment when you set the integer to 0.

Comment: @FalconC, as I said I can set them to 0. But this means when I try and increment (using intname++) they stay at 0.

Comment: @VishnuprasadR I said SharedPreferences worked, that's not the problem. M-WaJeEh I'll add code. Vishnuprasad again, no, incrementing means add 1.

Comment: Where does intName come from (where is it declared)?

Comment: um that's just below class extends activity, but as I've said many times that's not the problem. This is not specific to my code, I'm just asking how to reset a variable! I don't know why my question is being downvoted, it's a perfectly legitimate question that I've researched?

Comment: What is preventing you from incrementing it after you reset it to 0?

Comment: That's my question!! It just stays at 0!

Comment: The question is being downvoted because it is extremely unclear on the issue at hand.  In java setting a variable to 0 has no effect on your ability to change it later.  If you could post the code that you used to clear the variable and then the rest of the class that contains the buttons that may help.

Comment: I don't see how it's unclear at all, I specifically asked the direct question on a separate line by itself. I'll post some code

Comment: just for reference, you even mentioned in your post _"This is part of the incrementing code. This works."_ and yes I agree.  That code does exactly what it says it increments `intName` by 1.  That however has nothing to do with your question, your question is about resetting the variable and we dont even know if its `intName` that you are trying to reset or where you declared it from as @FalconC mentioned.  You need to give us a complete understanding of the situation.

Comment: Well I thought I had, but I guess everyone understands things differently. To be fair it doesn't help that 2 of the 3 downvoters were not english and one did not even understand incrementing which is a key part of the question. Anyway, thanks to you for being more civil and I've posted the code.

Comment: @user2503325 To clarify I didn't downvote you. If you got offended by my comments please know that I just want to help you.

Comment: I understand it can be frustrating and that a lot of times (its just the way humans think) we ask questions without context because we are so familiar with the context we don't realize why others are confused.  Getting some downvotes on a question is nothing to lose sleep about, anyways I think i found the issue hold on

Comment: Don't worry Falcon, I'm not offended, and sorry I was trying your code but I'd closed the emulator and it's really really slow to reload. Chancea, I'm just annoyed because it's halved my reputation and now I can't do anything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Prefs", 0);
Editor editor = prefs.edit();

Button PlusOneButton = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.plusonebutton));
PlusOneButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(!sharedPrefs.contains("myIntPlusOneSaved")) {
            editor.putInt("myIntPlusOneSaved", 0);
            editor.commit();
        }
        intName++;
        PlusOne.setText(String.valueOf(intName));
    }
}

Button ResetButton = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.resetbutton));
ResetButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(!sharedPrefs.contains("myIntPlusOneSaved")) {
            editor.remove("myIntPlusOneSaved");
            editor.putInt("myIntPlusOneSaved", 0);
            editor.commit();
            intName = sharedPrefs.getInt("myIntPlusOneSaved", 0);
            PlusOne.setText(String.valueOf(intName));
        }
    }
}
```

Try it out and say if it works.

I assume you have tried the following solution, and it didn't work:

```
Button PlusOneButton = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.plusonebutton));
PlusOneButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        intName++;
        PlusOne.setText(String.valueOf(intName));
    }
}

Button ResetButton = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.resetbutton));
ResetButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        intName = 0;
        PlusOne.setText(String.valueOf(intName));
    }
}
```

Change the name of the variables/constructors/etc. to fit in your code.

Comment: on the 2nd `setOnClickListener` you are calling it on the `PlusOneButton` again... probably meant `ResetButton`... I think this actually just like is the OP's problem to begin with (see my answer)

Comment: Right, when I tried your code the int didn't set to 0 when I clicked the reset button. It just stopped incrementing when the +1 button was clicked (or kept displaying the same value) but when I pressed back and then back to the activity it displayed the int, including the increments I'd clicked before. That probably doesn't make sense but say it said 2, I pressed reset then pressed +1 3 times, it would stay at 2 until I went to the previous activity then back again at which point it would say 5.

Comment: Not sure who upvoted my question but thanks a lot, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Okay, on the !sharedpreferences part of your answer I'm getting an error because it can't find the sharedpreferences in an onClick() method, which is why I got into the method() and method2() mess. Any tips?

Comment: @user2503325 Do you get a runtime error? If not, please try the updated code. It should update the counter directly. If it is a runtime error, let me know.

Comment: Nope, no runtime errors. I'm just trying out your answers, and thanks so much for the upvote :D

Comment: @user2503325 No problem. Could you try the new solution. I have fixed some variable problems. If this doesn't work, please let me know what the problem is. I really want to see this work.

Comment: Okay, I've checked that I've implemented your code exactly, and I'm getting 3 errors. I had to put `SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);` just before the if/else statement of the first bit of your reply to find `sharedPrefs`, but it cannot find `getSharedPreferences`. The third error is the same, with the second part. I had to add the same line.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the edit, be 2 mins. By the way, thanks for the upvote, I've upvoted both of your answers now I have the ability!

Comment: Right, getting the same errors as last time (`.getSharedPreferences') but I'm also getting an error on getInt because it requires (String, int) not (String, null).

Comment: @user2503325 The initialisation of sharedPrefs seems sketchy. I Could you initialise it as this:`SharedPreferences Sharedprefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Prefs", 0);` and 
`Editor editor = prefs.edit();`. Also, you're right about getInt, it should be `0`, not `null`.

Comment: Just edited my question to clarify error. I had some problems with SharedPrefs, I found loads of ways to do it and this was the only one I could find that worked but I'm no expert, I may have done it wrong!

Comment: Your initialisation doesn't seem to change anything, it doesn't bring up any new errors but doesn't get rid of the original ones

Comment: Ouch. It seems like I can't solve this. It's a very strange bug indeed, logically resetting an int should still make in incrementable.  [But I have found a sample app that does what you want](http://md-android.blogspot.nl/2011/12/create-android-counter-clicker-app.html), except for the SharedPreference save. Take a look at that code, and put this in `onPause()` and `onStop()`: `editor.putInt("myIntPlusOneSaved", intName); editor.commit()`. That seems to be the only argueable good solution to this strange, unlogical problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'd misread your answer and there are no errors in eclipse now. However, when the app is run, there is a runtime error when opening the activity. It's a classcastexception at line 41 (string cannot be cast to int) and I'll show you the line in my code in original question. It's weird because I'm sure there's no error, holding mouse over the variables says whether it's an int or string and they look fine! Anyway, thank you for finding the sample app, I'll have a look.

Comment: That app was great thanks, I've got the counter to work now. The only problem is now `SharedPreferences` isn't saving, that's my next task now!

Comment: Okay, I've got it all sorted! I'm not 100% sure what it was that fixed it but it was mainly down to that app you linked, so I'll give you the answer and thanks so much for the help! I'll also edit my question with the working code so you can see the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see is that you have 2 methods for your on click listener

The first one is your increment method that you posted originally:

```
Button PlusOneButton = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.plusonebutton));
        PlusOneButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                intName++;
}});
```

the second one uses `method2` declared inside of `method`:

```
public void method(View view) {

    Button PlusOneButton = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.plusonebutton));
    PlusOneButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                method2();
        }
    }); 
}
```

I do not see the code where you actually call `method` but once you do, you override the `onClickEvent` that fires within the button as such the first `setOnClickListener` will **never** be called again.  I assume this is happening because I quote:

> I've also tried setting them equal to 0, but then I can't increment
>   them any more. Is there a way to just reset or delete variables?

As you can see in your method 2:

```
public void method2() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
        myIntPlusOne = 0;
}
```

You do not ever increment the `myIntPlusOne` again and just like you said after you have cleared it, it would never increment again.

You really should use 2 separate buttons (one to increment, one to clear) and use 2 separate `onClickListeners` for each button.  You can see @FalconC's example for that

Hopefully that makes sense :)

Comment: ah okay, I think I understand. Basically, I used the method() and method2() which confused me too at first because SharedPreferences had problems when it was inside onClick, so I moved it out. I assumed that if I went back and pressed the incrementing button it would increment again, but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: I dont really know your whole setup, the biggest issue I saw was just that you are calling `setOnClickListener` twice for the same button.  a button can only have **one** click event when it is clicked.  You **changed** the click event from **incrementing** to **resetting** after you call `public void method(View view)` and so after that every time you click the button it will continually **reset** the variable and not **increment**

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some dead code when you click your ResetButton. You check if `myIntPlusOneSaved` is **not** in the preferences and you try to remove it. Personally, I would delete this condition:

```
ResetButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
        Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("myIntPlusOneSaved", 0).commit();
        myIntPlusOne = 0;
        TextView PlusOne = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.plusonetextview));
        PlusOne.setText(String.valueOf(myIntPlusOne));
    }
});
```

For your ClassCastException, I think you put a String in your preference in the past and now you try to access it with `getInt`. Check if you have some `putString("myIntPlusOneSaved", xxx)` somewhere and replace them with `putInt`. It's possible that you have a String in your preferences from an older version of your application. You can then remove your application and reinstall it or remove only the `myIntPlusOneSaved` preference.